# Comparing a string array with object array

Tags: javascript

I want to compare two arrays

```
array1=["123',"456"];
array2=[{id":"001",name:"prashant"},{id:"123",name:"jhh"},{id:"123444",name"baak"},{id:"456",name"sxs"}];
```

my objective is to extract the objects from array2 whose ids match the values in array1.

Can someone help me with the optimal solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The intersection code is for two arrays with a similar structure. Please look at my two arrays. the structure is different

Comment: that's even one step lesser than having both arrays of objects.

Comment: Also possible duplicate:　[How to remove object from array except matching value?](//stackoverflow.com/q/58127808)

Comment: I extracted id's into a different array and then compared it that works.  However I feel this can be optimised as this is a very crude method and can be optimised.

Comment: yes it can be if you convert your first array into a `Set`. then the method `array.includes` of `O(n)` will be changed to `Set.has` `O(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your second array (*array2*) is syntactically invalid.

You can try with [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var array1=["123","456"]; 
var array2 = [{id:"001",name:"prashant"},{id:"123",name:"jhh"},{id:"123444",name:"baak"},{id:"456",name:"sxs"}];

var res = array2.filter(i => array1.includes(i.id));
console.log(res);
```